# hibernate "Identity" generator

Tags: spring, hibernate

Can the id be manually set in hibernate if the id is specified as "**Identity**" in the hbm file?
i.e. can i call the **.setId()** method while i have set the id as "**Identity**" in hibernate hbm file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course call method, but it will cause problems later on. Such a attribute is persisted the identity column in database. Often value in such a column cannot also be updated via SQL.

If you want to set values by yourself, do not use identity columns in database. Also use *assigned* (default) as a generator.